# Nagios 4; Need a way to see the history of a service

Tags: nagios

I need to work out the history of a service in nagios. So I clicked on the service, then "View history for this service", but just get an error saying "No history information was found for this service in the current log file". I've looked at our log files in /usr/local/nagios/var, and found nagios.log, but the file is rotating once a day, which seems reasonable. There are a lot of other temp files in that directory with names of the format nagios.tmp[0-9a-z]{6} which I presume are the rolled over logs for other days, but they're in a different, less amenable format. I'm thinking that nagios only looks at the first log file then gives up.

So how do I view the whole history through the web interface whilst maintaining the log rotation?

Comment: Were you able to click through the archive log files? (There should be an arrow )

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend running something like the following (you may want to adapt what you actually grep for, to make the search more restrictive, and/or pipe to a second grep after the first that does a further selection of rows before the numerical/`-n` sort):

```
grep -rni "HOST;SERVICE" /usr/local/nagios/var | sort -n | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e' | gzip > /tmp/myservice.gz
```

This command will:

- grep recursively through anything below `/usr/local/nagios/var` for that string (`HOST;SERVICE`)
- sort the output numerically: assuming UNIX timestamps, this means output will be in order regardless of what order the file are grep:d in
- use perl to convert all unix timestamps to a human readable format (localtime)
- compress the output to `/tmp/myservice.gz` for inspection with `zless`

There's the potential for this command to take a very long time, so you can experiment with what files to actually grep (perhaps `2019*`) if you wish to limit the scope, and/or you could grep by UNIX timestamp as well with a regex.